# Is there a complete example/tutorial (or at least an alternative to wxODBC) for CodeBlocks + Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, codeblocks

I am just starting to program Code::Blocks with Postgres. I haven't tried any other DB platform either with it.

So far I've found that DB connections and coding can be done using wxODBC. wxWidgets is what I use for the UI. I found this: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_odbcoverview.html

But I found these lines regarding postgres on the web page.

> - Does not support the keywords 'ASC' or 'DESC' as of release v6.5.0
> - Does not support sub-queries in SQL statements

So I'm concerned about even the simplest queries being able to run.

My key question: Is there a complete example/tutorial on how to use wxODBC with Code::Blocks? If so, I'd appreciate a link.

Secondary questions:

1. If there's such an elementary problem, what is the workaround?
2. Is wxODBC the default way of doing things or is there a better/easier way of doing it?

A million thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching AND testing, I have come up with the following conclusions as my answer and I hope this will benefit others considering the use of wxWidgets with C++.

1. There is documentation on http://docs.wxwidgets.org but this is not very useful because of the way it's presented.
2. There's a samples folder that you get with wxWidgets. This provides quite a number of complete examples. Unfortunately if you're a new coder to code::blocks, you'll have trouble opening these projects. This is because most of them are not meant for or built with code::blocks but with other systems like Borland C++ or MS VC++. But you can still open the files using your editor or code::blocks.
3. I'd advise against the use of wxODBC because with different DB platforms it has different issues. Two such cases are shown in my question above. But I guess this is a 'phase' of the project and I hope it gets fixed. And until then, it's not for me or any other serious business that plans to use my combination (C++ with Postgres).
4. wxODBC is not the default. there's no such thing as the default. But libpqxx is the standard way of doing things and it's very popular. But it has no GUI support and a lot of conversions to and from wxWidgets is needed when working with PG (at least).

So in conclusion, I am compelled (at least for now), to go with libpqxx for C++ on Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that wxODBC is essentially dead, it was dropped in the 2.9 branch and won't be in 3 which is due to come out soon. You should probably not consider it at all for new code.